# CI upload image validation h/w error with 'human' field?

Tags: codeigniter, validation, file-upload

I'm uploading two images which have two different dimension requirements.

When the validation rule is set, the second parameter (the 'human readable' field as CI docs say), is set. I use a custom validation callback function to process the image validation (set config, call upload->do_upload() ). The error message I get back is generic "The image you are attempting to upload exceedes the maximum height or width."

How can I pass through the human readable name of the field being validated (e.g. "image 1" or "image 2") so the user knows which error message relates to which image upload field?

Edit:
I've come up with a partial solution:
By prefixing the validation set_message with the field name, I can now group the errors under a heading. However the problem is now different. The custom validation function is the same for each image with a different parameter, but if both have an error message, the second grouping shows both it's own and the previous.

For example, Image 1 is too large in file size. Image 2 is too wide. Error message for Image 2 shows too large file size and too wide.

I don't really want to duplicate the function just for the sake of this...

Comment: For clarification, I don't have a problem with uploading images. I already have a single image upload working perfectly fine. Now there is more than one image, I need to make the image validation errors say which field it is related to.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into what i think is a similar thing in the past.

If you are looping through your uploaded files, with different `$config` for different files, you need to initialize the the upload class between each iteration:

```
$this->upload->initialize( $config );
```

Do you have pastebin or something of a code sample?

This is what I did in an earlier project to handle changing $config depending on file type:

if( $_FILES )
{
    $this->load->library('upload');

```
foreach ( $_FILES as $key => $value )
{
    $file_type = ( $key == 'image' ) ? 'image' : 'document';

    if( ! empty( $value['name'] ))
    {
        $config = array(
            'upload_path'   => './uploads/materials/' . strtolower($material['code']) . '/',
            'allowed_types' => ($file_type == 'image') ?  'jpg|jpeg|png' : 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf',
            'max_size'      => 1024 * 10,
            'max_width'     => 19200,
            'max_height'    => 12800,
            'overwrite'     => TRUE,
        );

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Here is the key idea: You need to initialize each time you change the $config
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $this->upload->initialize( $config );

        if( $this->upload->do_upload( $key ))
        {
            //Success! Files are all uploaded.
            $uploaded = $this->upload->data();

            $data['file_data'] = array(
                'parent_id'         => $data['material']->id,
                'filename'          => $uploaded['file_name'],
                'filename_original' => $uploaded['client_name'],
                'type'              => $file_type,
                'location'          => $config['upload_path'],
                'description'       => '',
            );

            // Add the file details to the database
            $this->material->add_material_file( $data );
        }
        else
        {
            // ERROR! Something went wrong... alert the user.
            $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->session->set_flashdata( 'flashError', $errors );
        }
    }
}
```

}